# Comment est le b apparu dans "humble"?

Tags: étymologie, phonétique

J'étais en train de penser comment expliquer la différence entre ***humble*** et ***humility*** en anglais, et je me suis rendue compte que cette différence a dû passer du français en anglais.

Sur l'étymologie du mot, le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/humble) dit

> a) Ca 1100 [d'une pers.] ici valeur adv. (Roland, éd. J. Bédier, 1163
> :
>
> - Vers Sarrazins reguardet [Rollant] fierement E vers Franceis ***humeles*** e dulcement);
>
> 1re moitié xiies. ***humle*** (Ps. de Cambridge, éd. F. Michel,
> CXXXVII, 6);
>
> b) id. [d'une chose] ***humele*** (ibid., CXII, 6).
>
> Empr. au lat. ***humilis*** (de humus) « près du sol, bas » fig. «
> humble, obscur, faible; modeste, conscient de sa faiblesse », ce
> dernier sens étant surtout attesté en lat. chrétien.

***Humle*** est le plus proche de ***humble***. Est-ce que quelqu'un sait comment ce ***b*** est apparu?

Comment: « Si le sujet est un nom, il est placé devant le verbe.  On ajoute alors le pronom personnel correspondant derrière le verbe. Exemples :     Pourquoi va-t-elle seule au cinéma ?    → Pourquoi Juliette va-t-elle seule au cinéma ? » ([Lingolia](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/la-phrase/la-phrase-interrogative))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un processus qui s'appelle l'[épenthèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89penth%C3%A8se) : l'introduction spontanée d'un son dans un mot. Comme le dit l'article Wikipédia, ce processus naturel aide à créer une prononciation plus « euphonique ».

Dans ce cas particulier, il y a deux sons côte-à-côte dont la prononciation est très similaire : `/m/` et `/l/`. Les deux sont des consonnes très sonores : une consonne nasale et une consonne liquide qui permettent toutes deux le passage non-obstrué de l'air. Les lieux d'articulation de ces phonèmes sont proches l'un de l'autre aussi (ils ne sont pas adjacents, mais plus proches que `/m/` et `/k/` par exemple).

Ce type de combinaison donne souvent lieu à l'[assimilation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phon%C3%A9tique)), c'est-à-dire le processus où deux phonèmes qui partagent certaines caractéristiques se rapprochent encore plus. Parfois, ils sont un peu trop éloignés et d'autres fois on risque de perdre le sens en ne pouvant plus distinguer un mot de l'autre. Dans ce cas, on trouve le phénomène contraire qui s'appelle la [dissimilation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissimilation). On peut penser à deux aimants, qui s'attirent ou se repoussent, mais ne peuvent pas rester neutres.

Parmi les moyens d'éloigner deux sons, on trouve l'épenthèse. C'est ce qui s'est produit dans le cas d' « humble » où le `/b/`, qui partage le lieu d'articulation du `/m/` mais qui est beaucoup moins sonore en tant que consonne occlusive, « coupe » le flux et permet ainsi une distinction plus facile du `/m/` et du `/l/`.<sup>1</sup>

On peut observer les deux phénomènes dans un autre mot qui a une histoire fascinante : « [hominis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hominis#Latin) ». En espagnol, c'est la dissimilation qui a eu lieu : au début, `/n`/ est devenu `/r/` (`/m/` et `/n/` sont presque identiques) ; par la suite, un `/b/` s'est introduit pour former  *hombre*. En français, par contre, le `/m/` et le `/n/` étant très proches, ce dernier s'est assimilé en `/m/`. (Ce même mot aurait d'ailleurs pu poser problème si *humilis* était devenu *humle* → *humne* → *humme*, par exemple.)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Notons que d'un autre point de vue, on peut dire qu'il n'y a pas de `/b/` qui s'introduit, mais tout simplement le découpage de l'air, ce qui fait la différence entre `/m/` et `/b/` — une petite pause pour dissimiler le `/m/` et le `/l/`. Il y a une différence théorique mais pas de différence articulatoire. Il est cependant peut–être plus facile d'expliquer, par exemple, le `/d/` de *humilde* en espagnol de cette manière.</sub>

Comment: « Chez » ne convient pas ; c'est une préposition utilisée pour les êtres animés ou les êtres non animés, mais dans ce dernier cas il s'agit soit de personnification  (litt.) soit d'un sens générique ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chez)). « Pour » est le mot de base, mais d'autres possibilités existent (que l'on peut utiliser si l'on n'aime pas « pour »), par exemple, « …s'est produit dans l'évolution de la prononciation de « humble » ».

Comment: @LPH Il me semble que tu aurais pu simplement le dire. Le posteur n'aurait aucun doute quant à ta compétence dans ce domaine, ni moi d'ailleurs. Tout ce formalisme fait un peu froid.

Comment: @Lambie Le plus familier on devient avec un sujet le plus on absorbe l'information facilement ; si on ne la retient pas la première fois il n'y a pas grand mal, on y reviendra ; mais il se trouve qu'il y a des personnes qui lisent vite et se souviennent de beaucoup de choses facilement, et c'est pour cela que l'on consigne _tout ce formalisme_,  par exemple dans des dictionnaires. Je ne fais que donner les grandes lignes (c'est un petit résumé). Je suis flatté de la confiance que vous me portez, mais que cette confiance ne vous empêche pas de faire les vérifications d'usage.

Comment: Il faut dans ces cas-ci, à mon avis, se rendre compte du niveau de la personne...Mais, bon, ça c'est juste mon opinion.

Comment: Cette condamnation de *chez* est un peu sévère. Je l'avais laissé inchangé car il ne me paraissait pas totalement déplacé, pouvant être compris comme un raccourci de *C'est ce qui s'est produit chez certains mots comme « humble » où le /b/ [...]*.